# Wordpress Hide child posts of custom post type in wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-admin

I created a custom post type called "Companies".
Every time a post of post type companies is created, a child post is also created.

I would like to hide the child posts of this companies post type in the backend.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: i am still struggling with this, does anyone have an idea?
Maybe i am able to create a specific page in the backend on which i can run a custom query, to only query the parent posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by using the following code:

```
function cleanup_companies_posttype_list($query) {
  global $pagenow;
    if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'companies' && $pagenow == 'edit.php') {
      $query->set('post_parent',0);
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'cleanup_companies_posttype_list');
```